# Logging real time output from subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, subprocess

Using subprocess in python3 -  i want to log output from the subprocess execution.

I have tried multiple implementation to solve this. I am not able to sucessfully get a solution need help.

Code:

parent.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import sys

with subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True) as proc:
    while True:
        byte = proc.stdout.read(1)
        if byte:
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(byte)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        else:
            break
exit_status = proc.returncode
```

child.py

```
#!/bin/env python3
import sys
from time import sleep

while True:
    for _ in range(8):
        print("test!")
        sleep(1)
    break;
```

Execution:

```
> ./parent.py ./child.py
test!
test!
test!
test!
test!
test!
test!
test!
```

**The output is not displayed in real time. (prints all lines at once at the end).**

if i directly execute `./child.py` on the terminal - **it prints each line with delay of 1 second as expected.**

**Note**:
If i modify print statement in child.py to
`print("test!", flush=True)`
then both the execution of child.py (via parent.py and directly on the terminal) print the lines at real time with the delay of one second.

Not clear on what is going on. Could someone please explain this behavior and
suggest changes to parent.py so that it can log output in real time without any changes to child.py